# Как программно узнать прошивку андроид?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли каким-то образом программно (!!!) узнать, какая прошивка установлена на андроид?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под прошивкой? Версию ОС?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // only for gingerbread and newer versions
}
```

или

```
public String getAndroidVersion() {
    String release = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    int sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    return "Android SDK: " + sdkVersion + " (" + release +")";
}
//ответ "Android SDK: 19 (4.4.4)"
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуй `System.getProperty("os.version"­);`